# Как убрать задержку после нажатия клавиши

Tags: java, разработка-игр, клавиатура

Пишу игру на процессинге. При нажатии клавиши LEFT герой сдвигается на пару пикселей, потом ждет доли секунды и только потом продолжает движение

```
void keyPressed(){    
  if (keyCode == LEFT) 
     hero.pozx -= hero.v0;
}
```

Такая же проблема:

```
void setup(){
  size(200,200);
}

void draw(){
  background(0,255,0);
}

void keyPressed(){
  rect(100,100, 100, 100);
}
```

Comment: в этом куске кода довольно сложно найти проблему.

Comment: попробуйте куда-нибудь выводить фразу "герой подвинулся"

Comment: @michael_best Я подозреваю, что проблема не в ошибке в коде, а в неправильном методе, сейчас добавлю маленькую программу-пояснение

Comment: А когда вы нажимаете кнопку влево в редакторе, разве курсор начинает двигаться без задержки?

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець в редакторе - да, а вот в играх - нет

Comment: Ниже есть ответ, на который я намекал)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы привязываете перемещение персонажа напрямую к событию клавиатуры, в результате, первое короткое смещение персонажа получаете после того как произойдёт событие одинарного нажатия клавиши, потом происходит задержка до определения клавиши как зажатой и повторный вызов этого события пока клавиша не будет отпущена. Попробуйте проводить перемещение персонажа по таймеру, а на события клавиатуры вешайте только изменения флагов нажатых кнопок. Пример:

```
boolean keyLeftPressed;

onKeyDown() {
    if (keyCode == LEFT)
        keyLeftPressed = true;
}

onKeyUp() {
    if (keyCode == LEFT)
        keyLeftPressed = false;
}

onTimer() {
    if (keyLeftPressed)
        hero.pozx -= hero.v0;
}
```